# how do I acces array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a web version of 4-in-a-row and store the tiles as a big array with arrays in it which represent the rows:
[image]

but when I run for example this:

```js
data[4][5]=1
```

all the 5th values change to 1 while I only want to change the 5th value of the 4th array to 1

Can someone help?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: You only have two arrays: an inner array, and an outer array which contains a whole bunch of references to the sole inner array. When you initialize your array make sure you make a distinct copy for each one (I.E. `arrays[i] = arrays[i-1].slice()`) or construct enough individual arrays (E.G. an expression starting with `[` should be reached `n` times while creating `n` arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the way the array is created.

You probably have `data[0]`, `data[1]`, ... `data[6]` all referencing the same array. You can check it easily:

```
data[0] === data[1] // will be true
```

It is important to create new array 7 times for each row.

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    data.push((new Array(7)).fill(0));
}

// data is
// (7) [Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7)]
// 0: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 1: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 2: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 3: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 4: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 5: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 6: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

data[4][5]=1
// data becomes
// (7) [Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7)]
// 0: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 1: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 2: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 3: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 4: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
// 5: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// 6: (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

// checking
data[0] === data[1] // false
```

Comment: Hey Vitalii, Tnx for your answer, This helped me a lot!